# Trying to set an image URL using a global asset field

Tags: globals, plugin-imager

I've setup a global asset field so that a client can change a placeholder image that gets used throughout their website. I'm using the Imager plugin for my image transforms.

The following image code works fine when using a hard-coded image URL:

```
{% set image = 'http://placehold.it/450x225/eee/eee' %}
{% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, { width: 450, height: 225, }) %}
<img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}" />
```

But when I replace the hard-coded image URL with the global asset field, it doesn't work:

```
{% set image = '{{ websitePreferences.placeholderImage.first.url }}' %}
{% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, { width: 450, height: 225, }) %}
<img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}" />
```

I get this error message (Craft/Exception):

> Source folder “/Users/stephen/Repositories/repo-name-here/public_html./” does not exist

If I output the global asset field elsewhere in the template, I get this:

> http://my-locl-url.dev/uploads/images/Placeholders/placeholder-image.png

If I hard-code this URL into my image code, the image works fine. So does anyone have any idea why using a global for the placeholder image in this way isn't working? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cause of the error you're receiving or not, but this is incorrect Twig syntax:

```
{% set image = '{{ websitePreferences.placeholderImage.first.url }}' %}
```

You'll never need to nest `{{ }}` inside of `{% %}` or visa versa in Twig.

This is correct:

```
{% set image = websitePreferences.placeholderImage.first() %}
```

Comment: I try the above >>>> {% set image = websitePreferences.placeholderImage.first() %} and I doesn't work for me.
it only output the name of the image "<img src="Craft Cms Vs Wordpress Card">"

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
{% set image = websitePreferences.placeholderImage.first.url() %}
```